# Testing lodash debounce in react-native functional component using Jest / Enzyme

Tags: javascript, react-native, jestjs, lodash, enzyme

I'm trying to test that eventually props.onPress is called, but I'm getting "TypeError: debouncePress is not a function". Any ideas why?

```js
import _ from 'lodash';

export const Button = props => {
  const { debounceTime } = props;
  const debouncePress = _.debounce(() => {
    if (props.onPress) props.onPress();
  }, debounceTime, { leading: true, trailing: false });

  const handlePress = () => {
    debouncePress();
  };

  return (
    <TouchableOpacity testID="touchableOpacity" onPress={handlePress}>
      {props.label ?<Text>{props.label}</Text> : props.children}
    </TouchableOpacity>
  );
};
```

Here is the test so far

```
it('should call onPress when press event occurs', () => {
    wrapper = shallow(<Button onPress={jest.fn()} />);
    wrapper.find({ testID: 'touchableOpacity' }).simulate('press');
    expect(props.onPress).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```

Comment: One issue I see is that `Button` is defined with an [arrow function expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) so `this` will end up being the `this` from the outer scope, which may or may not have `props` defined.  I think you meant to do this: `const { debounceTime } = props;`.  As for the error you are seeing, did you mock `lodash`?  That's the only thing I can think of that would cause `debouncePress` to not be a function.

Answer (score 0):

I can't see where you pass `debouncePress` in your test!!

```
wrapper = shallow(<Button onPress={jest.fn()} />); // you passing onPress but debouncePress is undefined
```

`const { debounceTime } = props;` expects that `debounceTime` is passed as a property but it is not in your test